# Rails 4 Formatting DateTime field in partial

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone, simple-form

I'm storing a datetime field in UTC, but the user can enter it in various time zones. I configure the time zones by setting a cookie via JavaScript. Here is my ApplicationController code:

```
before_filter :set_timezone

def set_timezone
  if !cookies["time_zone"].to_s.blank?
    Time.zone = cookies["time_zone"].to_s
  end
end
```

I'm storing the times using nested attributes on another controller's form. Here is the partial that renders to fields via simple_form and simple_fields_for, passing in the form as 'f':

```
<div class="row fieldset">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <%= f.input :day,  collection: days, selected: f.object.day %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <%= f.input :open, as: :string %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <%= f.input :close, as: :string %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <%= f.input :_destroy, as: :hidden %>
    <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The time zone conversion is working correctly. I can enter times in the time zone that JavaScript detects, and then it will store them in UTC. It also displays them in the detected time zone, but prints out the full format:

```
2014-07-22 05:00:00 -0700
```

I believe the fields are strings by the time they get to the view, and that's why setting the value of the input field to the following doesn't work:

```
<%= f.input :close, as: :string, input_html: { value: f.object.close.to_s(:short) } %>
```

I'm just testing the 'short' formatting option. Figured I can add a custom one later.

Do I need to format the times in the controller for the controller with the nested attributes? Or can I format them in the model that handles storing the times? Let me know if you need more information or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if these are the best options, but here are the two I found:

1) Pass an instance variable to the partial with the fields value. Instance variables allowed me to format the datetime field using `to_s(:custom_format)`.

2) I'm using Simple Form, and found that using their time format worked well. For example:

`<%= f.input :close, as: :time, ampm: true, minute_step: 15 %>`

You can pass through any of the [default datetime_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/datetime_select) parameters to Simple Form.

The second option adds the meridian option (AM/PM) to the hour field, which was a little strange to me. But it seemed to be the simplest solution of the two, so I went with that for now.

[image]